# How to specify redirect uri using WebAuthenticationCoreManager?

Tags: authentication, uwp

I am using the `WebAuthenticationCoreManager` to authenticate an UWP app:

```
WebTokenRequest webTokenRequest = new WebTokenRequest(provider, authority, clientId);
webTokenRequest.Properties.Add("resource", resourceId);
WebTokenRequestResult wtrr = await WebAuthenticationCoreManager.RequestTokenAsync(webTokenRequest);
```

I am given the clientId and redirectUri to use, but I don't know how to set the redirectUri for the request.

[This thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/373e465f-1c2c-468a-b4ba-2ae20e6882b3/uwpc-how-to-set-redirect-uri-in-webtokenrequest?forum=wpdevelop) says there is no way, short of using the `WebAuthenticationBroker`, but I'm hoping that has changed.

So, is there a way to specify the redirect uri?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there a way to specify the redirect uri?

You don't need to set the redirect Uri with Web account manager relative APIs.

It seems like the redirect Uri is built in, and you cannot set it. The purpose you are using these APIs are for requesting a user's permission to use their Microsoft account and obtain an access token. You can just get the access token successfully without setting the redirect Uri. Just confirm having the app manifest being modified to use the App Identity of a registered Microsoft Store/registered AAD app. More details please reference the [WebAccountManagement official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WebAccountManagement) and the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager).

If you met an error like "The reply address .. does not march the reply address configured for the application ... " which should be same with [the above thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/373e465f-1c2c-468a-b4ba-2ae20e6882b3/uwpc-how-to-set-redirect-uri-in-webtokenrequest?forum=wpdevelop) you referenced, as Roland Oldengarm said, you may copy `ms-appx-web://Microsoft.AAD.BrokerPlugin/packageId` to your azure AD to try to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response!  Copying the redirect uri above to my azure AD resolved the issue.